# How to show recently viewed mail as a view/search in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there a way of seeing the last X mails viewed in outlook?

Inbox is not an option as I have lots of rules/folders in place and quite often work with 'old' mails

No, I don't want to use follow-up flags

Answer (score 2):

Like the poster above said, I don't think this is technically possible.

However, I use a feature that might meet some of the OP's needs: Recent Searches.

> [Screenshot: Recent Searches] (Outlook 2010):

[image]

Not as good as a "recently viewed items" would be, but it usually meets my needs.

Answer (score 1):

No way. Outlook does not timestamp emails when you're viewing them. And this is done for a reason: writing changes to messages can be time consuming and can lead to client-server synchronization.

Comment: Could live locally, just like web history does. I mean, they provide that so you can see recent stuff, why isn't this extended to mail too?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to use an Outlook search folder? You can specify an advanced lookup rule to only show messages from the last x days, combining this with the filter "read" you should be able to achieve your criteria.

Within Outlook navigate to "**Folders -> New Search Folder**" Then within the wizard, at the bottom under the **Custom** heading choose "**Create a custom Search Folder**"

This is similar to email rules, within the custom search window you can choose the options I mentioned such as only showing read messages and on the "**Advanced**" tab you can choose a date range. - I've enclosed a screenshot below as an example.

[image]

It's all quite self explanatory using the wizard. - Note a useful search folder I use is "Unread Mail" - This saves me clicking in to all my folders and I don't have to disable my sorting rules either.

Comment: "Received" is not "Viewed/Opened".